# Integral representability of compact operators on L_2

Tags: compact-operators, integral-operators

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain and $K: L_2(\Omega) \to L_2(\Omega)$ a compact linear operator. Does $K$ in general have an integral representation, i.e., is there an integrable function $k \in L_1(\Omega)$, s.t.,
$$
K(\varphi)(x) = \int_\Omega k(x, y)\varphi(y) \mathrm{d} y \text{ for all } \varphi \in L_2(\Omega)?
$$
If not, what are examples for such compact operators, that do not possess an integral representation?

Comment: The keyword you might want to look up is the notion of Hilbert-Schmidt operators, and I do not think that all compact operators are Hilbert-Schmidt but I wouldn't be able to give you an example myself right now.

Comment: Ah I misread and thought you put $k \in L^2$ instead of $L^1$, so $K$ is not always Hilbert-Schmidt.

Comment: For my specific case I know that it is not Hilbert-Schmidt unfortunately. That is also the reason why I require it to be in $L_1$. I was wondering if one might be able to show that it is weakly singular or something more general. It would be sufficient to show that it is in $L_1$ for my case though.